# Magento 2: Facing issue in "Edit Configurations" can't save product

Tags: product, product-attribute, configuration, magento2.3.1

I faced issue in `"Edit Configurations"` of product, can't save products, in `Magento 2.3.1` with `Apply images for all`.

**Error:**

> The
>   "/var/www/html/magentosample231/pub/media/tmp/catalog/product/d/o/download.jpeg"
>   file doesn't exist.

**Step to Reproduce:**

> Step 1) Got to product and Edit the product.
>
> Step 2) Click on Edit configurations button.
>
> Step 3) Select new option for attribute.
>
> Step 4) Apply single set of images to all SKUs
>
> Step 5) Click on "Generate Products" button
>
> Step 6) Now "Save" the product.

After save the product thrown error.

**Expected result:**

Product should be updated or Save successfully.

**Actual result:**

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please check your browser console ajax requert at the time if image upload

Comment: At the time of image upload ajax request working fine and also Image were uploaded in directory.

Comment: check you pub/media/tmp folder and it's permission.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your folder permissions , check this info for more https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Comment: folder permissions is correct. It's cause of the Edit Configurations time upload images.